# how to use structs as variables in c?

Tags: c, struct

basically im trying to use structs as variables in my programme. so i have created a typedef struct type with two variables(one a char* and the other a struct of that type) and when a struct of that type is passed into a function, it assigns value to the char variable of the struct variable and then passes that struct into that function again(since its recursive) that probabaly made no sense so hopefully u can workout what i mean by looking at the code! i have never used structs before so im kind of confused. i cant post the entire code here so im just gonna make up a random basic example. I defined it like this:

```
typedef struct person
{
    char* gender;
    struct person relative;
};

void randomfunction(struct person person)
{
    if(person.gender=="female")
     {
       return;
     }
     person.relative.gender = "male";

    randomfunction(struct person relative);
}

struct person john
{
   gender="male";
   relative;
}

int main()
{
    randomfunction(john)
    return 0;
}
```

Im currently getting these errors:
 error: field ‘relative’ has incomplete type

warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };

error: expected expression before ‘struct’
     randomfunction(struct person relative);

If anyone can tell me how to do this right, fix my code or has any helpful comments about something i might be doing wrong, plz go ahead! thnx

Comment: Doesn't your C textbook explain how to do this? This is basic syntax.

Comment: Sounds like that's your first mistake. Are you trying to learn C by trial and error?

Comment: lol no. i learned it through youtube tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not compile

1. You don't have a type name for your `typedef`, but you don't need to `typedef` anything, since you declare your instances with `struct person instance`, so the `struct` definition should be

   ```
   struct person
   {
       char *gender;
       struct person *relative; // This must be a poitner since
   }                            // struct person has an incomplete
                                // type at this point.
   ```
2. You cannot initialize the struct like this

   ```
   struct person john
   {
      gender = "male"; // This is invalid (if it's not it's the wrong language)
      relative;
   }
   ```

To alter the instance of `struct` that you can declare in `main()` (*you don't need it to be global*), you should pass it's address as a pointer to the function, like this

```
void randomfunction(struct person *person)
{
    if (strcmp(person->gender, "female") == 0)
     {
       return;
     }
}
```

Also,

1. You cannot compare strings with the `==` operator in [c](/questions/tagged/c), that just compares the pointers and almost surely the comparison will result in `false`, to compare strings you need [`strcmp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html).
2. You cannot modify the `relative` field of your `struct` directly, i.e. without allocating space for it, you need something like

   ```
   void randomfunction(struct person *person)
   {
       struct person *relative;
       if (strcmp(person->gender, "female") == 0)
        {
          return;
        }
        person->relative = NULL;

        relative = malloc(sizeof(*relative));
        if (relative == NULL) // On allocation failure
            return; // Now `person->relative' is `NULL'
        relative->gender = "male";
        // Make `person->relative` point to a valid `struct person'
        person->relative = relative;
   }
   ```

   you would use this function, like this

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       struct person person;

       person.gender = "female"; // Initialize it or it would be a
       person.relative = NULL;   // problem to call `randomfunction()'

       randomfunction(&person);
   }
   ```

Comment: Actually, string literals always have static storage duration, so you CAN assign a string literal to a const char * field or variable and it will be fine.  Whether you really want to or not is another question.

Comment: i got most of it. but im a bit confused. why did u put "struct person *relative;" in the randomfunction if its already in the struct person?

Comment: @csbk It's just to make the code cleaner, declarations are not really executable code. And the assignment is cheap and nicer to write than `person->relative->gender`.